# XSL node subset based on a set of multiple possible attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an XML like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<root>
<config>
<kids block="A">
 <owner name="bob"/>
 <owner name="alice"/>
</kids>
<kids block="B">
 <owner name="Jimmy"/>
 <owner name="Bimmy"/>
</kids>
<kids block="C">
 <owner name="Johnny"/>
</kids>
</config>
<objects>
  <object owner="bob">
    <name>fish</name>
    <value>200</value>
    <part>head</part>
    <part>tail</part>
  </object>
  <object owner="alice">
   <name>cat</name>
   <value>100</value>
   <part>claws</part>
   <part>head</part>
   <part>tail</part>
  </object>
  <object owner="Jimmy">
   <name>DoubleDragon</name>
   <value>0</value>
   <part>dragon</part>
  </object>
</objects>
</root>
```

I want to get the following

```
Output:
A - bob - fish
    alice - cat
B - Jimmy - DoubleDragon
```

listing all object names on a per Block then per owner basis. There is only one object per owner, so that would not be a problem.

Is it possible to produce such an output in XSL 1.0?

What I achieved through an ineffective `for-each` was to go through each block and then through its owners and search each owner in the `<objects>` section. But this does not allow for a fancy, hierarchical output, instead I get

```
A - bob - fish
A - alice - cat // note the duplicate A block name
B - Jimmy - DoubleDragon
```

---

Current XSL I have used

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="/root/config/kids/owner">
<xsl:variable name="ownername" select="./@name"/>
<xsl:text>     
</xsl:text>
<xsl:variable name="ownedObject" select="/root/objects/object[@owner=$ownername]"/>
<xsl:if test="$ownedObject">
 <xsl:value-of select="../@block"/> <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/> <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="$ownedObject/name/text()"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you currently have tried? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I have added valid input and the current XSL (for testing purposes) as demanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest you use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to link the objects to their owners.

Now, to achieve the wanted result you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="obj" match="object" use="@owner" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- for each block that has actual owners -->
    <xsl:for-each select="config/kids[key('obj', owner/@name)]">
        <!-- for each actual owner in this block -->
        <xsl:for-each select="owner[key('obj', @name)]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- for the first owner in this block -->
                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@block"/>
                    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>  - </xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('obj', @name)/name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the nested `xsl:for-each` instructions which ensure that the position() function operates in the context of the current block.

---

An alternative approach would process the objects and [group](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) them by their owner's block.

Answer (score 1):

> What I achieved through an ineffective for-each was to go through each block and then through its owners and search each owner in the  section. But this does not allow for a fancy, hierarchical output, instead I get...

Do it the other way around. Iterate over the `kids` elements, and for each one, iterate over the matching `objects/object` elements.

Comment: I added an XSL snippet. However, I am not sure if that's enough. I can't figure out the logic that gets rid of the redundancy - how can I avoid outputting the name of a block several times? How can I make sure that I output the name of the block if and only if that block of kids has at least one corresponding object?